# Why do movie directors use brown tint on Mexico cities?

Tags: analysis, production

Here is the satirical meme about Mexico cities in movies:

[image]

Movies like *Traffic* (2000), the plot took place in Mexico cities, also used brown tint a lot.

Why do movie directors use brown tint in Mexico cities?

Comment: It seems cherry picking... you have one movie example and an image that doesn't even come from the said movie.

Comment: @SilverBebs, not a movie, but Breaking Bad definitely has this. Robert Rodriguez movies has that too.

Comment: To other commenters: if it attempts to answer the question, it should be posted as an answer. (That's what they're for!) Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question or for asking necessary clarifying questions, not for posting unsupported answers.

Comment: @V2Blast sometimes one feels they don't have enough to make a solid answer, but feel it's worth mentioning a possibility of a potential answer. This can help both the OP better clarify their Q by having a brief conversation AND sometimes it does lead others to use the information to form a better answer.

Comment: **Not All Movies Do That** <br>
The movie ["Romancing the Bride"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wBVr-1AHpQ) is a good example. Of course it's basically a 90 minute advertisement for Mexican vacation resorts disguised as a romantic comedy. It's still decently watchable given the caliber of the acting talent and a good script. If anything, they go for the typical amber lighting and soft focus of most romantic movies. They don't let that interfere with the spectacular outdoor shots though.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From the [trivia page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181865/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) on imdb for Traffic:

> To achieve a distinctive look for each different vignette in the story, Steven Soderbergh used three different film stocks (and post-production techniques), each with their own color treatment and grain for the print. The "Wakefield" story features a colder, bluer tone to match the sad, depressive emotion. The "Ayala" story is bright, shiny, and saturated in primary colors, especially red, to match the glitzy surface of Helena's life. The "Mexican" story appears grainy, rough, and hot to go with the rugged Mexican landscape and congested cities.

Film processing (or digital processing filters) is often used in films to convey mood/heat/other emotions.  This is all that's in play here.

Mexico is often viewed as being hot and claustrophobic - the film treatment here (and in other films) uses this to enhance the mood of the film.

Additionally,

Soderbergh's rationale for differing colour temperatures and grain effects in different strands of the story of "Traffic" can easily to be applied to other directors and films.  Directors can and do use film treatments, editing styles, and music in order to enhance the emotional impacts of scenes, characters, events, and entire films.

It's outside the scope of this answer to include exhaustive examples.  However, the main point of this answer is that directors aren't likely to apply film treatements in order to convey a stereotypical perception of any particular location, although this may occasionally be the case.

Comment: This answer only really explains Traffic, the question is asking about Hollywood in general.

Comment: I don't think that it takes a huge leap of imagination to assume that other directors also use similar techniques and reasons when applying treatments to films.

Comment: @user While the OP makes the claim that this is "always" being done, they only provide the example of Traffic.  This answer directly addresses the reasons for this choice in that film.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner no need for pedantry. In this context, "always" means "common", not 'universal operator' in set theory. And yes it is common. See for instance the mariachi trilogy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D7ogIMnRq4 most outdoors scenes have very warm, often extreme pallettes. Compare to indoors / club nightscenes in the same trailer.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner: Here's another example from Breaking Bad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeVWpQUfmag

Comment: In Breaking Bad's case, they were showing that the segment was a *flashback*, simulating the yellowing of old photos and film.  Still doesn't explain Mexico.

Comment: Also, Breaking Bad takes place in New Mexico [which is not a part of Mexico](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=12512979).

Comment: @user1118321: Yup. And New-York isn't in England, just as New-Orleans isn't in France. Who knew? This specific scene was shot in New Mexico, but is supposed to take place in Mexico. See https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Don_Eladio%27s_Hacienda

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Adding those quite diverse examples to the question would definitely improve it, you guys could edit them in if the OP doesn't.  (It's best if the questions/answers can stand alone without referencing the comments.)

Comment: @grimm-the-opiner Are you expecting OP to literally list every single example ever made?  What's the correct number of examples for a general question?

Comment: @industry7 `What's the correct number of examples for a general question?`  It's certainly more than one.  Three seems fine, especially as we then have one gritty thriller, one bubblegum actioner, and one high quality TV series.